# Using LibXSLT (xsltproc) as an external engine in Altova's XMLSpy

Tags: xslt, altova, libxslt, xmlspy

I am trying to use LibXSLT as an external engine in Altova's XMLSpy, but keep getting an IO error when merging. What am I doing wrong?

Runline:

[image: ![enter image description here]

Error:

[image]

Comment: Do you get more information if you add `-v` or `--verbose` as a command line option for xsltproc? Have you tried without the `-o` option or with the `-o` option but then unchecking the `show external program output` checkbox?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions! I tried them: 1. For the --verbose, I'm getting what seems to be the log of the full merging process, but eventually the same IO error, without any explanation... 2. Without the -o the merge fails whatsoever (should it work normally? The merging fails for me without the -o when running it via cmd for example) 3. Unchecking the "show external" does not change anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switched to the following runline, the additional "file:///" before the -o parameter seems to do the trick:

X:\LibXslt\Xsltproc.exe -o file:///%2 %3 %1

[image]